# Why NSolve does not work?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation, but it does not work. I am very new to Mathematica so I am probably missing something very simple:

```
NSolve[(-a*x+x^2-b+b*x*Coth[x])*(-1+x^2*Csch[x]^2)==0, x, Reals]
```

This returns "NSolve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve". Why?

Comment: Because `NSolve` give a numerical solution. If you specify the values of `a` and `b` it works.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I think I needed to use `Solve`, then, as I need a functional solution. However, this gives the same error message.

Comment: That's a transcendental equation which I don't think has an analytic solution (except for some very special values of `a` and `b`).

Answer (score 10):

`NSolve` gives a numerical solution, so `a` and `b` need to be specified; then it works.

You can get an insight into how does the solution depend on the parameters `a` and `b` like this:

```
f[a_, b_] := 
 x /. NSolve[(-a*x + x^2 - b + b*x*Coth[x])*(-1 + x^2*Csch[x]^2) == 0,
     x, Reals][[1]]
```

to produce a table

```
tab = Flatten[#, 1]& @
    Table[{a, b, f[a, b]}, {a, 0.1, 3, 0.1}, {b, 0, 3, 
      0.1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {42.2379, Null}

and plot the results

```
plot1 = ListDensityPlot[tab, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
   (* or *)
plot2 = ListContourPlot[tab, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]
[image]

Finally, you can also interpolate the results:

```
inter = Interpolation @ tab

inter[0.12, 2.37]
```

> 0.067048

which for this well-behaving equation works very well:

```
f[0.12, 2.37]
```

> 0.067048

```
Plot3D[inter[x, y], {x, 0.1, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

[image]